# Weird behaviour comparing template type-aliases to types via template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I work a lot with template meta-programming in c++, and I recently encountered some curious behaviour while attempting to write a type-trait to compare an indirect template template to a type.

I was trying to match the signature of a given `template template` parameter with a type to determine whether or not the type is an expansion of the template. The trait is simple:

```
template<template<typename> class Template, typename T>
struct is_template : std::false_type{};

template<template<typename> class Template, typename T>
struct is_template<Template,Template<T>> : std::true_type{};
```

This works as expected for explicit types:

```
template<typename T> struct Template{};

static_assert( is_template<Template,Template<int>>::value, "" );
```

But it gets interesting as soon as we apply any level of indirection using type aliases. For example:

```
template<typename T> using type = Template<T>;

static_assert( is_template<type,type<int>>::value, "" );
```

will fail to compile with clang and icc, but not with gcc.

I've tested this behaviour with `g++` (up to pre-release version 7), `clang++` (up 4.0 rc2), and `icc` (16 and 17); each time compiling with `-std=c++14`. It seems `g++ 4.9.0` and above is able to properly compile this, whereas `clang++` and `icc` can't.

A live example can be seen [here](https://godbolt.org/g/CG90br).

My question is this; is this level of template indirection well-defined by the standard? Or is this some sort of gray-area and/or compiler bug that I've just unluckily happened to stumble into? I tried finding the answer in c++1z's `n4618` draft of the standard, but couldn't find anything conclusive (though I may have missed it).

Hopefully someone can help clear this up for me!

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `tatic_assert( is_template<type,type<int>>::value, "" );`?

Comment: Yes, good catch -- thanks!

Comment: FWIW, it works fine with g++ 5.4.0.